# Excel to SQL import using VBA - How to only update the last few rows to database?

Tags: sql, vba, excel

In my Excel worksheet, there is a macro that can import the contents from Excel to a table in SQL. However, because there is thousands of lines of data, the macro process is time consuming if I want to only update newer rows in my Excel sheet, since the macro starts from the very 1st row.

Here is the macro code in VBA for reference:

```vb
Sub syncSQL()

   On Error GoTo EH

   Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
   Dim iRowNo As Integer
   Dim proj, inv, desc, edt, dt, time, details, stat, rmks, loc, okng, astk, pstk, pic As String
   Dim sconnect As String
   Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
   Dim sSQLQry As String
   Dim ReturnArray

   With Worksheets("Entry Form")

    'Open a connection to SQL Server'
    sconnect = "driver={SQL Server};server=server;database=IOT;uid=ID;pwd=PWD"
    conn.Open sconnect

    'Skip the header row'
    iRowNo = 4

    'Loop until empty cell'
    Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
        proj = "'" & .Cells(iRowNo, 1) & "'"
        inv = "'" & .Cells(iRowNo, 2) & "'"
        desc = "'" & .Cells(iRowNo, 3) & "'"
        edt = "'" & Format(.Cells(iRowNo, 4), "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'"
        dt = "'" & Format(.Cells(iRowNo, 5), "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'"
        time = "'" & TimeSerial(Hour(.Cells(iRowNo, 6)), Minute(.Cells(iRowNo, 6)), Second(.Cells(iRowNo, 6))) & "'"
        details = "'" & .Cells(iRowNo, 7) & "'"

        'Replace single quote with 2 single quotes'
        details = "'" & Replace(.Cells(iRowNo, 7), "'", "''") & "'"

        sSQLQry = "select * from [IOT].[dbo].[Maintenance] where [Project] = " & proj & " And [Invoice] = " & inv & " And [Description] = " & desc & " And [Entry Date] = " & edt & " And [Date] = " & dt & " and [Time] = " & time & " and [Problem + Repair Details] = " & details & ""

        rs.Open sSQLQry, conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

        'insert new record if does not exist'
        If rs.EOF Or rs.BOF Then

            'generate & execute sql, import excel rows to sql table'
            ssqlstring = "insert into [IOT].[dbo].[Maintenance]([Project], [Invoice], [Description], [Entry Date], [Date], [Time], [Problem + Repair Details]) values (" & proj & ", " & inv & ", " & desc & ", " & edt & ", " & dt & ", " & time & ", " & details & ")"
            conn.Execute ssqlstring

        End If
        iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
        rs.Close
      Loop

       MsgBox "Data imported."

       conn.Close
       Set conn = Nothing

   End With
   Exit Sub
   EH:

    MsgBox Err.Description
    Debug.Print sSQLQry
    Debug.Print ssqlstring

End Sub
```

To solve this issue, I want to make another macro similar to this one, but only insert the last 100 rows of data into SQL. That way I can import only the newer data, skip through the old data and speed up the process.

Problem now is that I'm not sure what is best used to add to my existing macro...

Comment: Just use one of the [ways to find last row](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba) minus 100 when you are defining your `iRowNo` variable

Comment: If (and I would hope so :) ) the SQL table you are seeking from has an id column, i would do the following. Before receiving data, you find the last row of your data and select the ID of the last entry. In the `WHERE` condition of the query you add `WHERE ID > VarID` Then you oden an ADO recordSet, save the query to it and use the CopyFromRecordset method to append the data. If that sounds like it could work for you and you need help at any of those point please ask :)